# Is possible to pass a method as Delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, casting, delegates

This is my scenario:

```
Class Test  
{  
    public int TestMethod(string s)  
    {
        return s.length; 
    }  

    public void TestInvoker()  
    {    
        var result = Invoker.Call( (new Test()).TestMethod,"String");  
    }  
}

Class Invoker  
{  
    public static object Call(Delegate method, object input) {... Do stuff ...} 

}
```

How can I do this? because "TestMethod" isn't a Delegate, i could do it with Func<>, but I want to avoid instatiate a Func<> delegate each time i use the invoker.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but only if the method accepts a concrete delegate type; not `Delegate` itself.

If you change your method to

```
public static TReturn Call<TInput, TReturn>(Func<TInput, TReturn> method, TInput input)
```

, it will work fine.

---

To be more precise, C# has an implicit conversion from a method group to a matching delegate type.

Comment: Thanks, i already suspected... but i thought that could exist something that do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Gracias! =) That's what i wanted to avoid "force" a Func delegate. But thanks anyway!